# colorbox href to sweetalert

Tags: html, colorbox, sweetalert2

I have to change a colorbox popup to sweetalert2 popup
my issue is that I'm using href attribute in colorbox to get HTML content 
and I couldn't find the same method in sweetalert2

Is there a solution for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's [.get() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp) to get the html data. What you would have to do is reference the html file.

Your javascript code should look like this.

```
  $.get("yourFile.html", function (data) {
     swal({
       html: data
     });
  });
```

Good luck!